# Postgres not using trgm index with Concat

Tags: python, django, postgresql, concatenation, pg-trgm

I created a trigram index on full name where full_name = first_name || ' ' || last_name.

```
CREATE INDEX  "user_full_name_trgm"
ON "user" using gin (upper(first_name || ' ' || last_name) gin_trgm_ops);
```

I am using django queryset to filter over fullname.

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(full_name=Concat("first_name", Value(" "), "last_name"))
queryset = queryset.filter(full_name__istartswith=full_name)
```

which generates WHERE clause as

```
WHERE (UPPER(CONCAT("user"."first_name", CONCAT(' ', "user"."last_name"))::text) LIKE UPPER('mike%')
```

The explain analyse shows that its not using `user_full_name_trgm` index. However when I use pipe to join the strings, the index is being used.

```
WHERE (UPPER(first_name || ' ' || last_name) LIKE UPPER('mike%')
```

How can I make django query to use the index? Can I modify query.annotate in such a way that it creates sql query without Concat? Or can I create index in such a way that it is used even with concat?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Postgres is not allowing concat to be used in index

Comment: Indeed. Sorry for the silly suggestion.